# Как растянуть кнопку по высоте на весь экран

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в WPF растянуть кнопку на высоту жкрана?(ширину при этом нужно оставить фиксированной)

Answer (score 2):

Например, так:

```
<Window xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="600" Width="800">
    <Grid>
        <Button Width="50"/>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Comment: Спасибо. Работает.

Comment: Пожалуйста!

Answer (score 1):

Нужно установить VerticalAlignment в Stretch, а ширину указать значением

```
<Button VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Width="100">Кнопка</Button>
```

То-же самое можно сделать и по горазонтали

```
<Button HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Height="100">Кнопка</Button>
```

Явна указаная ширина и высота имеет приоритет над соответствующим Alignment.